# Laravel and MySQL JOIN

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

i have a problem with this query... i need insert 2 more joins..

```
->join('torneo as t','t.idtorneo','=','p.id_torneo')
```

and

```
->join('temporada as s','s.idtemporada','=','p.id_temporada')
```

to run:

```
->select('p.idpartido','p.id_temporada','t.nombre_torneo as torneo','s.temporada as nombre_temporada','c.nombre as team1','k.nombre as team2','p.estado')
```

And i have this code working... but when add the other joins.. it fail.

"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052"

```html
public function index(Request $request)
    {
     if ($request)
     {
      $query=trim($request->get('searchText'));
      $partidos=DB::table('partido as p')
      ->join('club as c','p.idteam1','=','c.idclub')
            ->join('club as k','p.idteam2','=','k.idclub')
            ->select('p.idpartido','p.id_temporada','c.nombre as team1','k.nombre as team2','p.estado')
      ->where('estado','=','Activo')
      ->orderBy('idpartido','desc')
      ->paginate(7);
      return view('partidos.index',["partidos"=>$partidos,"searchText"=>$query]);
     }
    }
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Are you sure this query is causing the error? That would be strange for a SELECT statement.

Comment: Hi, integrity constraint might be related with your foreign keys, can you update your question and show us your migration files?

Comment: I dont use migration file... i make the database with phpmyadmin for testing

Answer (score 1):

There might be a problem with the data as you are using `->join` which is `innner join` in Mysql try to use `->leftJoin` which wont let the query break if the data is available it will make a join else it will leave the selected column from joined table as blank hope it helps :)

Comment: i change join for leftjoin and add
        ->leftjoin('torneo as t','p.id_torneo','=','t.idtorneo')
and 't.nombre_torneo as torneo_nombre' in select and... error:

Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'estado' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `partido` as `p` left join `club` as `c` on `p`.`idteam1` = `c`.`idclub` left join `club` as `k` on `p`.`idteam2` = `k`.`idclub` left join `torneo` as `t` on `p`.`id_torneo` = `t`.`idtorneo` where `estado` = Activo)

Comment: where clause is ambiguous try to give an alias name to your selected columns for example if I am joining two tables `T1` and `T2` which have id column as common then if I want to select T1's id column I would do something like select ('T1.id').